# Adding button object to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I Need help adding a button to a cell of my `DataGridView`. It's not working with the code i'm using (see below).

I'm getting an error: `No best type found for implicity-typed Array`

```
DataGridViewButtonCell btn = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
this.dataGridView1[0,100] = btn;
this.dataGridView1[0,100].Value = "Button";
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is to add the 2nd column on this row with a button:  (but it's not working)

`dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "A:", (button goes here) , textbox1.Substring(648 , 2) })`

Comment: The second line should have worked and made the 1st cell in the 100th row a buttonCell. If it exists. The 4th line makes no sense.

Comment: Adding a row wouldn't be replacing a row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
int index = DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
DataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2] = New DataGridViewButtonCell(){ Value = DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value}
```

Comment: A btn is a string?

Comment: Oops! Let me try something. I'll test using object instead of string. I didn't see you were trying to insert 2 string and your button.

Comment: I updated my answer. I tried thoses 2 very lines in VB.Net with success.

Comment: Use the @name format in comments to reply to someone.  You should use the returning index of the row: `int index = DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");`  Then you can use that index: `DataGridView.Rows[index].Cells...`

Comment: Ok thanks @LarsTech I'll update the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @MichaëlCorriveau-Côté  Hi. That didn't work for me. It doesn't like the "New DataGridViewButtonCell" part of it. I'm doing this on C# by the way.